# jquery get height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 divs.

```
<div class="bg1"></div>
<div class="bg2"></div>
<div class="bg3"></div>
```

And I'm trying to get the heights of them and set their css with jquery.

```
$('[class^=bg]').each(function(key,val){
     // tried, val.height() val.outerHeight val.innerHeight, this.height() etc
});
```

`console.log(val)` just shows `<div class="bg1"></div>` instead of a jquery object, how would I go about getting and changing the height of each div in this loop?

Comment: There is not one div with a class of bg mentioned.

Comment: instead try $(val).height();

Comment: @Kiee are you trying to get the combined heights? Separate heights? I don't understand what you're trrying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much @Neablis that did the trick, josh I was trying to get the heights of each individual but through the foreach opoposed to 3 calls to .height()

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that your functions don't work because `val` is a DOM object instead of a jQuery object.
You can get the effect you want by converting each `val` DOM object into a jQuery object by wrapping it with `$()`.

This code should work the way you want:

```
$('[class^=bg]').each(function(key,val){
    $(val).height();
    // or $(val).height(100) etc.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your code a little bit by adding a new class.

```
<div class="bg bg1"></div>
<div class="bg bg2"></div>
<div class="bg bg3"></div>
```

then you can proceed to not use jquery easier.

```
var dom = document.getElementsByClassName('bg'), height = '50';

for( var x = 0; x < dom.length; x++ ){
    dom[0].style.height = height;
}
```